Grouped Stacked Bar Chart - border radius applied only to last element of series
I have an issue about border at Grouped Stacked bar chart. I can't add border radius at all bar column.


I tried to add
 plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '90%', // Adjust this value to control the width of bars
        horizontal: false,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderRadiusApplication: 'end',
        borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'last',
      },
    },

this not work for me

Could you add a bit more information to what your expected result is?

With the option borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'all' you get the first image; with borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'last' you get
the second image. Although it is not stated in the question, I suspect you want the radius to apply to "Income" and
"Cost of Goods Sold" and not to "Expense", which I think is a very natural thing to expect.
Unfortunately, the option borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'last' only applies the radius to the last series in the whole chart, and not
for the last series in each stacked group, as one might expect. By looking at the source code
I can see that the implementation of barRadius and borderRadiusWhenStacked ignores the behavior of groups.
The best thing to do is to fill a feature request or even a bug report on github.

Meanwhile, a hacky solution can be devised, by getting a hold of the bar Helpers class that contains the shouldApplyRadius
method and changing that method so it matches the intended outcome. Note that the following code is experimental and might very well stop
working for any future updates of apexcharts.

getting hold of the Helpers class can be done after chart.render() has already completed (the returned Promise is
fulfilled), through chart.rangeBar.barHelpers

a simple the new version for the borderRadiusFunction that works only for this particular case (with three bar series, two groups) is
shouldApplyRadius = function(realIndex){
      return (realIndex === 0 || realIndex === this.barCtx.lastActiveBarSerieIndex)
}

which applies the radius for the series index === 0 and for the series that is the last active (normally index === 2,
but if visible, otherwise index === 1)
Here is a code snippet that implements these ideas.




const options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Income',
            group: 'budget',
            data: Array(4).fill(null).concat([44000, 55000, 41000, 67000, 22000, 43000])
        },
        {
            name: 'Expense',
            group: 'actual',
            data: Array(4).fill(null).concat([48000, 50000, 40000, 65000, 25000, 40000])
        },
        {
            name: 'Costs of Goods Sold',
            group: 'actual',
            data: Array(4).fill(null).concat([20000, 40000, 25000, 10000, 12000, 28000])
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 350,
        stacked: true,
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            columnWidth: '90%', // Adjust this value to control the width of bars
            horizontal: false,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderRadiusApplication: 'last',
            borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'last',
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i)=>String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0)+i))
    },
    colors: ['rgb(168, 160, 252)', 'rgb(192, 100, 100)', 'rgb(252, 170, 100)']
};

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render().then(() => {
    chart.rangeBar.barHelpers.constructor.prototype.shouldApplyRadius = function(realIndex){
        return (realIndex === 0 || realIndex === this.barCtx.lastActiveBarSerieIndex);
    };
    chart.updateOptions({}, true, true);
});
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>




The following code snippet contains a version of the function shouldApplyIndex that should have a generic range of applicability,
being able to detect the indices of the last active bars for each group. It also contains the original code of the function from github (linked above).



const options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Income',
            group: 'budget',
            data: Array(4).fill(null).concat([44000, 55000, 41000, 67000, 22000, 43000])
        },
        {
            name: 'Expense',
            group: 'actual',
            data: Array(4).fill(null).concat([48000, 50000, 40000, 65000, 25000, 40000])
        },
        {
            name: 'Costs of Goods Sold',
            group: 'actual',
            data: Array(4).fill(null).concat([20000, 40000, 25000, 10000, 12000, 28000])
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 350,
        stacked: true,
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            columnWidth: '90%', // Adjust this value to control the width of bars
            horizontal: false,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderRadiusApplication: 'last',
            borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'last',
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i)=>String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0)+i))
    },
    colors: ['rgb(168, 160, 252)', 'rgb(192, 100, 100)', 'rgb(252, 170, 100)']
};

function _getLastSeriesInGroupIndices(w, barCtx){
    const lastGroupIndices = [];
    const groups = [];
    w.config.series.forEach((series, index)=>{
        if(series.data && series.data.length > 0 && !barCtx.zeroSerieses.includes(index)){
            const group = series.group;
            const groupIndex = groups.indexOf(group);
            if(groupIndex >= 0){
                lastGroupIndices[groupIndex] = index;
            }
            else{
                groups.push(group);
                lastGroupIndices.push(index);
            }
        }
    });
    return lastGroupIndices;
}

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render().then(() => {
    chart.rangeBar.barHelpers.constructor.prototype.shouldApplyRadius = function(realIndex){
        const w = this.w
        let applyRadius = false

        if(w.config.plotOptions.bar.borderRadius > 0){
            if(w.config.chart.stacked){
                if(w.config.plotOptions.bar.borderRadiusWhenStacked === 'last'){
                    const lastGroupIndices = _getLastSeriesInGroupIndices(w, this.barCtx);
                    if(lastGroupIndices.includes(realIndex)){
                        applyRadius = true
                    }
                }
                else{
                    applyRadius = true
                }
            }
            else{
                applyRadius = true
            }
        }
        return applyRadius
    };
    chart.updateOptions({}, true, true);
});
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>



